# How can I apply the same condition in the different datasets in the python pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing a machine learning project to predict the strong area of a department using many datasets. In that case, I need to apply the same condition to different columns of different datasets.

For example:

```
Condition = [
(X['Y'] >= 3.75) & (X['Y'] <= 4.00),
(X['Y'] >= 3.50) & (X['Y'] < 3.75),
(X['Y'] >= 3.25) & (X['Y'] < 3.50),
(X['Y'] >= 3.00) & (X['Y'] < 3.25),
(X['Y'] < 3.00)
]

category = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
X['Y'] = np.select(Condition , category, default='0') #np for numpy libraries
```

Here, X is the particular dataset, and Y is the column name.

When I run the code, it shows

```
NameError: name X is not defined
```

How can I use "X" as the different dataset name and Y as the column name?

Comment: Where is `X` defined in your code?

Comment: @NathanFurnal In the Condition, I used X nine times. I want to use this X as the dataset name.

Comment: You don't show where the error happens, nor do we know if `X` is defined. The error means that there is no variable with that name.

Comment: @NathanFurnal I understand the problem that you mentioned. Is there any way to solve this issue??

Comment: Yes, show us where and when `X` is created.